# ProgressBar.setVisibility() not working in onActivityResult

Tags: android

In my app, Activity B is launched from Activity A.  When Activity B is finished (app returns to Activity A), the app runs Function C inside onActivityResult(), which works perfectly.

Now, I add a ProgressBar in Activity A to indicate that Function C is running.  Before running Function C, I set the visibility of the ProgressBar to View.VISIBLE and set it back to View.INVISIBLE when Function C is finished.

The structure of my program is:

```
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        functionC();
    }

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

However, it doesn't work: while Function C still runs like before, the ProgressBar never appears.

I am wondering if we're allowed to manipulate UI inside onActivityResult().  If not, is there a workaround?

Any suggestion to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Function C:

```
        firebase.authWithPassword(mLoginEmail, mPattern, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                handleAuthenticated();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                showErrorDialog(firebaseError.toString());
            }
        });
```

Not sure if Function C has any influence on the visibility of the ProgressBar.

Comment: if command will take a sec to complete its task hence progress bar wont be visible..what is in functionC?

Comment: if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   functionC();
    }

Comment: Thank you.  I tried to both mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) inside the if statement but the problem is still there.

Comment: Function C is an OAuth function which does take a while to finish.

Comment: That's for multithreading exists....

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in `onActivityResult`, I put `mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE`)  in `Handler` it work perfectly

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });


    if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        functionC();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

           ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            functionC();
        }
    }
```

and in functionC() put,

```
((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

hope it will hell you

Comment: Seems like you do not understand ui thread... Any changes on ui done inside method called on ui thread will be not "visible(ui update)" until this method returns... So setting visible then invisible in such method makes no sense...

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to achieve the progressbar feel untill u fetching something from the net or your function does extensive operation requiring 2 3 seconds to complete

As a hack you can have a timer of 2 3 seconds and enable and disable the progress bar if you so kneen to show that

Comment: I don't like hack buddy!